# Get Conf Parameter From Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, app-config

I have to prepare a report which is getting some fields data from conf file and show related data on report.

I prepare a conf file and i can read it's data with C# but i can not compare them with ms sql's data. To sum up, i want to show my own sql query's result with Crystal Reports and i want to get Where statement's values from a conf file.

Is there any document or something like that? I can not find an effictive document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build the Crystal report with parameters then use those in the record selection expert. You can read the app.config values using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["parameter_name"].ToString()` then pop them into the crystal parameters using:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions ;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition ;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = textBox1.Text;
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["Customername"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 

        }
    }
}
```

Taken from: http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm